# List groups own content and all non-group content on groups page

Tags: 7, organic-groups, views

I building a site where some content (eg. news, events) that either belong a group (region) or not (national).

On the national part of the site I have a view in a block that presents all content filtered by type (news or events). No problem...

On the regional part(s) of the site I want to have a view that show all the news (or events) that is published by that region. This is no problem either. (OG contextual filter etc.)

But I also want to include all news that don´t belong to a region at all.... this part I can´t figure out.

What I want to happen (under the hood) in the SQL is this...

The WHERE-part that I get from Views:

```
WHERE ( ((og_membership_node.gid = '<gid>'))
  AND (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('news')) )) )
```

Change that to:

```
WHERE ( ((og_membership_node.gid = '<gid>') OR (og_membership_node.gid IS NULL))
  AND (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('news')) )) )
```

Perhaps hook_views_query_alter() or hook_views_pre_execute() can fix this...

Comment: Work as I want if I fake it... By setting a filter to **news** AND (**group_id** IS NULL OR **group_id** == [gid]) where gid is fixed to any known gid. But I want it to be dynamic and fetch gid from the context (current result when trying is to get no result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! I used hook_views_query_alter().

```
function MY_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if (strpos($condition['field'], 'og_membership_node.gid') === 0) {
          $condition_group['conditions'][] = array(
            'field' => 'og_membership_node.gid',
            'value' => NULL,
            'operator' => 'is'
          );
          $condition_group['type'] = 'OR';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```